# color sides of 3d pie chart in highcharts

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I want to make a pie chart where i can give color to the side of the 3d pie chart, which is the darker blue color.

i can configure the lighter blue color, but the side color is taken based on the main color of the pie.

i want to individually color both the main surface and the sides.

```js
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'pie',
    options3d: {
      enabled: true,
      alpha: 60
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      depth: 150,
      animation: false,
      states: {
        hover: false
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [
      ['apple', 8]
    ]
  }],
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>tyre</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="container"  style="height: 400px"></div>

  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/adapters/standalone-framework.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still udpate colors using `element.attr()` option. There is `point.graphic` which contains all shapes for the slice.

Example below updates color on load and redraw event. You may want to use `point.events.mouseOver/mouseOut` to apply different color when hovering slice and restore your color.

```js
function updateColors() {
    var chart = this, 
        graphic = chart.series[0].points[0].graphic; //get first slice

    graphic.side1.attr({ fill: "red" });
    graphic.side2.attr({ fill: "orange" });
    graphic.inn.attr({ fill: "black" });
    graphic.out.attr({ fill: "yellow" });
    graphic.top.attr({ fill: "grey" });
}
 
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'pie',
    events: {
      redraw: updateColors,
      load: updateColors
    },
    options3d: {
      enabled: true,
      alpha: 60
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      depth: 150,
      animation: false,
      states: {
        hover: false
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [
      ['apple', 8]
    ]
  }],
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>tyre</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="container"  style="height: 400px"></div>

  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/adapters/standalone-framework.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but color resets on hover. any idea?

Comment: Yeah, read my answer again, about `point.event.mouseOver` ;) Apply colors again in that events.

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot adjust both color and shadow, unless you don't want the shadows to show at all. Using the colors option you can change the color of the slices, but the shadow is a shade of that color. If in the colors you use color names instead of hexadecimal values the color will whitewash everything and no shadow will be displayed.

```js
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'pie',
    options3d: {
      enabled: true,
      alpha: 60
    }
  },
  colors: ['#008000' ],
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      depth: 150,
      animation: false,
      states: {
        hover: false
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [
      ['apple', 8]
    ]
  }],
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>tyre</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="container"  style="height: 400px"></div>

  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/adapters/standalone-framework.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yep, i found that i can change the color, but i was wondering if i could alter the shadow of the pie. thanks for your help though :)